# Count the question marks in a string, when the question marks are mistakes from conversion

Tags: plsql, count, converters, plsqldeveloper

I need to count the question marks in a string like this:

```
From?l?   
B?l?m
```

This would be easy with this code:

```
regexp_count(string, '?')
```

But the problem is, these are not real question marks, they are mistakes from conversion. In this way I got the number of characters in the string. They were like exactly like these:

```
Fromálé
Bülű
```

So the question is, how can I count these conversion mistakes in a string?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you know which characters are errors? Do you have a list?

Comment: All the question marks are conversion errors. I need to count these errors by counting the question marks.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Can you please post some sample data and needed result to clarify your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the "?" with "\" as in: '\?'.  Otherwise, you are wild-carding.

Comment: How simple was that! Thank you!